# How to INSERT INTO Table with SELECT and auto incremented field

Tags: sql-server, insert, auto-increment

I am trying to insert from a table I created into a production table - I was able to do this earlier with a formula that I think caused duplicates and did not populate the primary key(In this case PROSPECT_ID properly. Since it is an auto incremented field and I am using a select from another table to INSERT any help on how to properly auto increment this field in production? MKT_PROSPECT

```
INSERT INTO MKT_PROSPECT(PROSPECT_ID,RECORD_TYPE,search_name,LABEL_NAME,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE,CUSTOMER_STATUS_CODE,COMPANY_NAME,JOB_TITLE,FORMATTED_DETAIL,ADDRESS_1,ADDRESS_2,CITY,STATE,POSTAL_CODE,ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE,ADDRESS_STATUS_CODE,HOME_PHONE,EMAIL,ADDOPER) 
select PROSPECT_ID,RECORD_TYPE,SEARCH_NAME,LABEL_NAME,FIRST,LAST,CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE,CUSTOMER_STATUS_CODE,COMPANY,TITLE,FORMATTED_DETAIL,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIP,ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE,ADDRESS_STATUS_CODE,PHONE,EMAIL,ADDOPER from dbo.prospects  
where SEARCH_NAME IS not NULL and LABEL_NAME is not null
```

Comment: Turn "IDENTITY INSERT ON"

Comment: If PROSPECT_ID is autoincrementing, just don't insert/select that field and it should auto populate correctly.

Comment: @John Hartsock on my table dbo.prospects?

Comment: Are you trying to insert your pre-specified "auto increment" values (aka surrogate keys)?

Comment: @Philip Kelley I am trying to let the table MKT_PROSPECT auto populate the auto incremented id PROSPECT ID.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson If I dont insert/select PROSPECT_ID this is my end result:  Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PROSPECT_ID', table 'SFNTST2.dbo.MKT_PROSPECT'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: `SQL Server` don't have auto_increment .. rather IDENTITY. Is this question specific to SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @Rahul MSSQL (SQL Server 2008r2)

Comment: Can you show your table schema/definition for `MKT_PROSPECT`

Comment: @Rahul here it is on screencast http://screencast.com/t/QcpC021jTo

Comment: @ShawnRahmani If you're getting a NULL error, you're trying to set it to NULL. Don't set it at all to have it increment.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, the suggestion provided by you is the best but look at the link Op have given in comment. His `prospect_id` is a PK but not IDENTITY column and moreover it's of `VARCHAR` type `not null`

Comment: @Rahul Ah, I read the question which says auto increment, apparently not the whole truth, thanks.

Comment: If I have understood correctly; your `MKT_PROSPECT(PROSPECT_ID)` is a `varchar` column and the table from where you are selecting there `prospect_id` is int auto_increment column. Weird structure really.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to insert into a table with a specific ID use [IDENTITY INSERT ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) as John Hartsock said in the comments. It is worth noting that the auto increment column will continue all other inserts (outside of the scope of the Identity Insert) above the largest number.

If you meant to insert and have the table auto generate you just don't include the ID column in the insert:

```
INSERT INTO MKT_PROSPECT(RECORD_TYPE,search_name,
                         LABEL_NAME,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE,
                         CUSTOMER_STATUS_CODE,COMPANY_NAME,JOB_TITLE,
                         FORMATTED_DETAIL,ADDRESS_1,
                         ADDRESS_2,CITY,STATE,POSTAL_CODE,
                         ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE,ADDRESS_STATUS_CODE,
                         HOME_PHONE,EMAIL,ADDOPER) 

             select RECORD_TYPE,SEARCH_NAME,LABEL_NAME,FIRST,LAST,
                    CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE,CUSTOMER_STATUS_CODE,COMPANY,TITLE,
                    FORMATTED_DETAIL,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIP,
                    ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE,ADDRESS_STATUS_CODE,
                    PHONE,EMAIL,ADDOPER from dbo.prospects  
                    where SEARCH_NAME IS not NULL and LABEL_NAME is not null
```

Comment: This is not going to help at all in OP's situation. Though the answer is correct.

Comment: @Rahul The answer was based on the original post before the OP went into detail about the problem. Thank you for reflecting that here